# Images in file do not appear when trying to run the file with a button press. (Tkinter and python)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
button_start = tk.Button(self, text= "Start", command=lambda: execute())
        button_start.pack(side=tk.TOP)
def execute():
    import horserace as hr
```

ouputs: "File "C:\Users\wwwul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 2805, in _create
return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage7" doesn't exist"

Question: We are trying to execute a file (horserace) with the press of a button (in tkinter), however, every time the button is pressed, the file is executed with no images (the canvas is loaded however none of the images are loaded in). How can we get the images to load with the file?

Comment: You're probably creating more than one instance of `Tk`, which isn't how tkinter is designed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not providing any code that runs I'll have to guess.

My guess is that the images are created by the import `horserace`. When the `execute()` function exits all references to the images are garbage collected.

For a better answer, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).